Elements in chrome browser are not clickable when opened with selenium, unless I leave the browser displayed
I am try to get get data from a site using selenium webdriver. Everything works well when I leave the browser opened/displayed on the screen, but when I minimise the browser tabs, nothing is clickable, no matter how long I wait for the page to load.
Does anyone have a solution to this?
Please find my code below?
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

import random

user_agents = [
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.1 Safari/605.1.15',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/16A366',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 12_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/16A366',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; Pixel 3 XL) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Mobile Safari/537.36',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4; en-US; Nexus 5 Build/KRT16M) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36'
        ]


options = Options()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options) 

driver.execute_script(f"window.navigator.userAgent='{random.choice(user_agents)}'")
trends_url = 'https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?cat=71&date=2023-01-01%202023-12-31&q=Minute%20Maid,Caraibos,Del%20Valle,innocent%20juice&hl=en'        
driver.get(trends_url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 200 ).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".widget-actions-item.export"))).click()


successful = True

It throws the error below
enter image description here
